# Laravel - Get raw query without execute this one

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I think this is a simple question but I can't solve.

How can I get raw query of a Eloquent query without execute this one.

Example:

```
$rawQuery = getRawQuery(Product::where('is_sold', '=', 1)->get()); // or something like that

echo $rawQuery; // select * from `product` where `product`.`is_sold` = 1
```

Comment: It already prints out the raw query as it's supposed to. Is that not what you want? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
$rawQuery = Product::where('is_sold', '=', 1)->toSql();
```

To get your bindings you can do:

```
var_dump(Product::where('is_sold', '=', 1)->getBindings());
```

Comment: Oh no! The result I got: select * from `product` where `product`.`is_sold` = ?
How can I get value passed to this query? (Maybe this is array(1).)

Comment: Yeah, bindings are separated from the query, just edited to show you how.

Comment: Thank you so much. (sad) I don't have reputation enough to vote you up.

Comment: At this point you should be able to accept a question, aren't you yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last query after you run it then you may use:

```
Product::where('is_sold', '=', 1)->get();

// Get the last query
$q = DB::getQueryLog();
print_r(end($q)); // or dd(end($q));
```

You'll get something like this:

```
Array ( 
    [query] => select * from `products` where `is_sold` = ? 
    [bindings] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [time] => 0.38 )
```

Also, if you want to log all of your queries then you may use `illuminate.query` event:

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time, $name)
{
    // use Log class to log queries
});
```

Or, you may use [clockwork](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/using-clockwork-for-debugging-in-chrome-developer-tools) (Chrome extension) to see all your query details in your chrome console, it's very helpful and you can configure it for `Laravel`, details in the documentation but there are also other `PHP/Laravel` packages available to use.